# Get column by name in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a small block and was wondering if Laravel provided this kind of tool.

I have columns in my database that are capitalized like this:

```
MEAL_ID 
MEAL_TYPE
```

In my model or my controller I can correctly call them in lowercase but in my view strangely if I call `$recipe->meal_id`, no line is displayed contrary to if I put `MEAL_ID`, I have no worries. So I was wondering if in my view, there was a possibility that it remains case insensitive as in the templates and controller.

Comment: if you are accessing the column case-sensitive then you can make an accessor in the respective modal. with that accessor, you can call anywhere!

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to ignore the Laravel naming conventions. I would advise you to change the columns in the database. It will make your application easy to maintain.

Comment: Your table name handle from your **database**, not from **PHP**

Comment: @sta on a windows system column names are case sensitive, on a unix system they are not (by default). So the problem could be in PHP or Blade.

Comment: @GertB. this this is from OS side, or from PHP side?

Comment: The columns in your database are capitalized, so your accessors need to be capitalized as well. That's because PHP is case sensitive and Laravel probably doesn't convert the database columns to lowercase to create the accessors.

Comment: `$recipe['MEAL_ID']` would work !?!